# Custom query in Spring JPA CrudRepository with partition

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, repository, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to figure out how I go around selecting some data from a specific partition through custom queries in Spring JPA CrudRepository.

Select some data through Workbench works fine with the following sql:

```
select * from employee partition(sep_2016);
```

So why isn't this working as a custom query when modifying it:

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM employee partition(:partition) e WHERE 
       e.name = :name AND e.age IN 
       :arrayOfAges")
```

Is it even possible to select from a partition with Spring JPA CrudRepository?

Comment: Stack trace? Error message? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: "partition"

Comment: Try adding nativeQuery to true:  `@Query("SELECT * FROM employee e partition(:partition)  WHERE 
       e.name = :name AND e.age IN 
       :arrayOfAges",  nativeQuery = true)`  if it is native it could work but as far as I know JPA doesn't supports `partition`